# How to test iptables settings by port scanning?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nmap, port-scanning

I want to test my iptables and prove that it only allows traffic for given Protocol / Port - combinations. How I can use as a target for a port scan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Portspoof](http://portspoof.org/) is a tool which will allow you to emulate a lot of services listening on a large number of ports. Its primary use is to confuse port scan attempts, but it may also fill your needs.